# Transaction from fragment to activity(java class)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

> FragmentOne

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {




    public FragmentOne() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, container,
                true);


        return view;
    }
}
```

Hello, i'm a begginer , i tried all i could find ,the problem is i need this fragment to initialize the class BaseAct.java  , after the fragment refers to a  activity_main2, i cound find anything so i hope you can help me , thank you in advice

i can link you all the source files if you need them

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BaseAct.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, container,
            false);


    return view;
}
```

> LogCat

```
Process: com.elitiv.myapplication2.app, PID: 2941
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.elitiv.myapplication2.app/com.elitiv.myapplication2.app.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.elitiv.myapplication2.app/com.elitiv.myapplication2.app.BaseAct}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.elitiv.myapplication2.app/com.elitiv.myapplication2.app.BaseAct}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1541)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3957)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityFromFragment(Activity.java:3932)
            at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1054)
            at android.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1033)
            at com.elitiv.myapplication2.app.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:23)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your question is how to initialize an `Activity` from a `Fragment`?

Comment: Yes of course,sorry if i was unclear in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a new `Activity` from the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` by launching an explicit `Intent`to the `Activity` you want to start.

Also, like rcoro says, please pass `false` to the 3rd parameter of `inflate()`. Passing `false` will prevent the framework from adding the `Fragment` to the hierarchy twice, which will result in an error.

Comment: I added the intent and the false value giving an error in logcat,maybe i didn't do it right ?

Comment: i did it , and below it is how i aded the intent

Comment: Like the stacktrace says. Have you added the `Activity` to your manifest?

Comment: now i did it ,thank you a lot sir it solved my problem